# Python - How to avoid error (Exceptions) in Pandas while still getting data ?

Tags: python, exception, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I'm currently using Pandas to get options data from yahoo. It works fine until there is a stock that does not have options, at which point the program crashes. I attempted to create exceptions and just have it pass but without luck. How can I have the program identify stocks with no options and just skip? Thanks.

The error I get is this: RemoteDataError: Data not available

Here's the code (I used a stock with no options to test--> 'GHC'):

```
from pandas_datareader.data import Options
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime
import csv
import time
import sys

tickers = ['GHC']

for i in tickers:
option = Options(i,'yahoo')
data = option.get_all_data()

try:
    print data.head

except AttributeError:
    pass

except RemoteDataError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *handle the `RemoteDataError` exception* imported from `pandas_datareader._utils`:

```
from pandas_datareader._utils import RemoteDataError
from pandas_datareader.data import Options

tickers = ['GHC']

for i in tickers:
    try:
        option = Options(i, 'yahoo')
        data = option.get_all_data()
    except RemoteDataError:
        print("No information for ticker '%s'" % i)
        continue
```

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine it is the code I'm executing and it works for me. What is happening on your end?

Comment: so when i run your code it works!!!!! Is it possible that having all those extra libraries at the top messed it up because when I ran it the first time I just made changes to my code to reflect your changes...

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in tickers:
    try:
        option = Options(i,'yahoo')
        data = option.get_all_data()
    except RemoteDataError: # Add here correct expectation type...
        continue # What to do with 'i' and 'data', nulls?
```

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine paste your error message from prompt.