# skip the error and continue to run after getting 3 errors in a loop - Getting Price data from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, yahoo-finance, skip

I'm creating a loop to iterate a function. The function is simply getting data from yahoo finance by a list of tickers. However, some tickers do not have data in yahoo finance and sometimes there has bug, so I need to re-run the function whenever I got this error.

Basically, re-run can solve the bug, but it can't help if there has no data in the database. So, I want to use a loop defining that if there has error, then re-run, but skip that ticker if there error appears 3 times for that ticker.

I think I have done something wrong in the loop, it didn't pass that ticker and it keep re-running even it's already getting error for that ticker for more than 3 times. May I know how can I solve it?

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pickle
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

def save_hsci_tickers():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:/Users/kman/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://www.hsi.com.hk/HSI-Net/HSI-Net?cmd=tab&pageId=en.indexes.hscis.hsci.constituents&expire=false&lang=en&tabs.current=en.indexes.hscis.hsci.overview_des%5Een.indexes.hscis.hsci.constituents&retry=false")
    tickers = []
    for name in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.greygeneraltxt td.greygeneraltxt,td.lightbluebg"))):
        data = str(name.get_attribute('textContent'))
        tickers.append(data)
    edit = [x for x in tickers if x != '']
    final = edit[::2]
    driver.quit()

    def yahoo_ticker(data):
        if len(data) <= 4:
            return data.zfill(4) + '.HK'
        else:
            return data[0:] + '.HK'
    yahoo_tickers = [yahoo_ticker(data) for data in final]
    with open("hscitickers.pickle","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(yahoo_tickers, f)

    print(yahoo_tickers)
    return yahoo_tickers

save_hsci_tickers()

def get_data_from_yahoo (reload_hscitickers=False):
    if reload_hscitickers:
        tickers = save_hsci_tickers()
    else:
        with open("hscitickers.pickle","rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2009,6,30)
    end = dt.datetime(2017,6,30)

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df =web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

attempts = 0
while True:
    try:
        get_data_from_yahoo()
    except:
        if attempts < 3:
            attempts += 1
            continue
        if attempts >= 3:
            pass
    else:
        break
```

Comment: you set `attempts=0` right before `if attempts < 3` ... effectively you just did `if 0 < 3` which of coarse is always True ..

Comment: you are setting attempts to 0 in every exception raised.

Comment: Also, if you want the script to handle each ticker independently, you'll need to track the failures for each ticker separately. There are lots of ways you can do this. One good way would be to use a dictionary: `{'ticker_a': 0, 'ticker_b: 1, ...}`

Comment: Thanks all of your help. Understood. I try to put attempts = 0 outside the While loop, but it seems not working too.

Comment: I just updated the script. I am not sure whether it's related to other issues in the previous formulas since Pass argument didn't work for skipping the ticker with no data, which is 1551.HK

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the issue. The solution is similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249835/python-how-to-avoid-error-exceptions-in-pandas-while-still-getting-data)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable attempts outside the while loop to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks. I try to put attempts = 0 outside the While loop, but it seems not working too. I think it's related to the pass argument. Even I use below codes, it didn't work. It's didn't pass the ticker which has no data.         
while True:
    try:
        get_data_from_yahoo()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        break

Comment: I have solved the issue. The solution is similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249835/python-how-to-avoid-error-exceptions-in-pandas-while-still-getting-data)